Seeking feedback on my $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$.
I'm seeking feedback on my understanding of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limit proof for quadratic functions, specifically for $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$.
After studying multiple proofs, I've noticed that while the general approach is similar, the justifications for certain steps often vary. Some explanations, such as "because $\delta$ is typically small, we suppose $\delta \leq 1$", don't seem entirely rigorous or satisfying.
Nevertheless, these various proofs have helped me grasp the overall idea. I've attempted to synthesize my understanding into the following proof. As I'm still new to this topic, I would greatly appreciate feedback on my work.

Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We wish to show that there exists $\delta$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ implies  $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$.
Working backwards, note that $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon \iff |x-a||x+a| < \epsilon$.
If $\delta$ exists at all, there must also exist a value of $\delta \leq 1$ that works. (☛ I found this a better reason than "because $\delta$ is typically small, we suppose $\delta \leq 1,$" as that latter leaves one wondering, "What if $\delta$ happens to be large?") Thus, it is sufficient to consider if it's possible to find $\delta \leq 1$. (☛ While I'm fairly confident that this is a correct claim, I'm not entirely sure). When $|x - a| < \delta \leq 1$,
$$|x + a| = |(x -a) + 2a| \leq |x-a| + 2|a| < 1 + 2|a| \implies |x - a||x + a| < |x - a|(1+2|a|)$$
Thus, as long as we also have $|x-a|(1+2|a|) < \epsilon$ or $|x-a| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$, we will have $|x-a||x+a| < \epsilon$.
To sum up, if it's possible to find a working $\delta$, it's also possible to find a $\delta \leq 1$. For $\delta \leq 1$, we will have a working $\delta$ if it also satisfies $\delta < \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$.(☛ While this statement sounds good to me in its current phrasing, if I had phrased it differently, i.e. "If it's possible to find $\delta$ at all, then it's possible to find $\delta \leq 1$. If it's possible to find $\delta \leq 1,$ then $\delta$ must be less than $\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$." At this point, it seems a bit illogical to conclude that "thus, $\delta$ exists" as the premises have been entirely hypothetical.)
By taking $\delta = \min\left\{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}\right\}$, we will have $$|x - a| < \delta \implies |x-a| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{|x+a|} \implies |x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$$ It follows that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = a^2$.

@RupertRybka Thank you! I just fixed it! Please let me know if there's anything else.

In general, questions on Math SE need to be fairly narrowly focused.  Putting a proof into the question box and asking "Is this correct?" simply isn't a good type of question for this format.  I think you are asking a more specific question---namely, "Why can $\delta$ be chosen smaller than $1$?"---but I think that the question needs to more clearly articulate that (if I am correct).  Otherwise, there are likely dozen's of similar proofs on this site already---please consult with those, first.

@XanderHenderson Thank you for your feedback. I've reviewed the "help" page linked in the closure notice. It states that a question needs more focus when it "has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct)" or "includes multiple questions in one." I don't think my post falls into either category.

For background, I've studied numerous proofs of this problem from various sources (MSE, YouTube, textbooks), but found some explanations unclear or unsatisfying. While I found one proof that I consider rigorous, it didn't address the ambiguities I encountered in other explanations. Instead of citing multiple proofs and asking for further explanation in various places (some could be nuanced and hard to articulate), I found it more efficient to reconstruct the proof, providing my own explicit reasoning for each step to clarify aspects I found less clear in other sources.

As I'm new to this subject, I believe a comprehensive review would be more beneficial than focusing on specific areas. The proof is relatively short, and given my limited experience, I may not accurately identify which parts require the most scrutiny.

I believe it is not the case that there is no valid answer to my request nor is it impossible to characterize one to be correct/incorrect. I also think that my request could be considered one question, "Is my interpretation of this approach correct?" I'd be surprised that this is not considered a valid question in a math study forum. However, I do acknowledge the possibility that my question is not appropriate for the typical expectation of this site and warrants closure.

If you reread the comment I left above, I explained exactly what I think the problem with this post is---it is not clear that you are asking only one question (one possible question which I see in the post is "Why can it be assumed that $\delta < 1$?", but this isn't the only question I see).  And you, yourself, have just said that there are many related questions on Math SE already which you are unclear about.  This further suggests that this question is not narrowly enough focused for this particular site.

@XanderHenderson That's fine! The possible question you suggested is not my confusion and my question-as noted in a comment above- is simply that "Is my interpretation of this approach correct?" I don't see how this can be more specific,. However, I understand that this may not be the type of question MSE expects and thanks for your information!

Indeed, if you are just looking for general feedback about your proof, this is not the right site for it.  You are essentially asking a [tag:solution-verification] question---if you read the advice on that tag, you should get a better idea of what is expected here.

See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4597/ and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35663/ .

@XanderHenderson Thank you very much for the pointers! I'm taking a look at those and see if I could improve my post!

@XanderHenderson I've edited the post, including my comments in various places. It looks a bit messy as I couldn't think of a better way to include comments. Please let me know if it works, and thanks for your useful pointers!

"If δ
exists at all, there must also exist a value of δ≤1
that works" is true but useless, so don't bother about it. Your goal is to find some δ which works, and you are perfectly fine if you find one which is moreover  ≤1. Same with the other additional condition ($\delta < \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$). "What if δ
happens to be large?" You are the master of δ. It won't be "large" if you choose it "small".

@AnneBauval Thank you! Sorry if I misunderstood you, but isn't the condition that $\delta < \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$ necessary as we need to point out which range of values $\delta$ should be chosen from?

$\delta\le\min\left{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}\right}$   is not "necessary" but sufficient, and you don't "need to point out which range of values δ
should be chosen from" but only some range δ
can be chosen from.

@AnneBauval I see. Thank you very much!
